# nginx redirct non existing directory to an existing one

Tags: redirect, nginx

A given wordpress site had once a given link http://www.website.com/link/ which existed but now doesn't exist and I need to redirect it (301) to an existing one: http://www.website.com/link-existing/
I tried a lot of things which doesn't work:

```
location /link/ {
     try_files $uri $uri/ /link-existing/;
    }

location /link/ {
     return 301 /link-existing/;
    }
```

Comment: I cannot see anything wrong with your second approach.

Comment: The second approach gives me 404 on /link/ instead of redirecting me to the existing link.

Comment: You will need to look at the access log to determine the sequence of events. As you can see, there is no 404 in the `location /link/` block, so either the `location` is never entered (in which case you need to look at your entire `server` block), or `/link-existing/` is causing the 404 (which the access log will confirm).

Comment: What I see is exactly what I am explaining: "GET /link HTTP/1.1" 404

Comment: Your `location` block is for `/link/` which does not include the URI `/link`.

Comment: I fixed that typo but still the same. One interesting thing: today I tried creating a directory named link with an empty index file within it and in this case the redirect worked well. If I delete the link directory the redirect will stop working ... The hole idea is that this is a wordpress site and we need to redirect 404 links in order to not get them indexed by google.

Comment: If the URI is not matching the location block, there must be conflicting statements in the surrounding server block. You should edit your question and add further details, including the `nginx` configuration for the `server` block, and any relevant entries within the access log.